# How to find newly created objects via gc.get_objects() which are causing a memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pytorch, garbage-collection

I've been trying to solve a memory leak within my code via monitoring the number of objects created. To give a short overview, I have a PyTorch module which trains to solve a problem by iteratively make a prediction and minimising an error over a given number of epochs.

I've been using the package `gc` to monitor the number of objects created within my script and it slowly rises (as does the RAM usage). Every epoch there's around 200mb-400mb of RAM increase. Is there a way to see which objects are new/differ between epochs? I.e. grab two different `gc.get_objects()` and see how they differ in memory size? And, more importantly, see which python lines are resulting in these objects increasing in memory usage which is causing my the memory leak!

Comment: Are you able to create a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: This is part of the problem the code is spread over a few files and is probably like 600+ lines long, so I'd say it's past being reproducible. I can try. The strange thing is I've ran this code on a different machine and the memory leak doesn't seem to exist at all. And, after further inspection of my code it seems that the number of objects only increases after the first epoch. After that it's a constant number of objects but the memory slowly increases still

Comment: The exercise of paring down the problem, by removing lines can often help clarifying what is going wrong, and allows others to try it.  With that said, an alternative would be to try using https://github.com/vmware/chap  What you would do is run the program uninstrumented and gather two cores using gcore, once after the first epoch and one several epochs later.  It might suffice to analyze the second core with chap, but if not, looking at the first core gives you room for comparison.  If you post the cores I can take a quick look.